# How to vectorise int8 multiplcation in C (AVX2)

Tags: c, x86, simd, intrinsics, avx2

How do I vectorize this C function with AVX2?

```
static void propogate_neuron(const short a, const int8_t *b, int *c) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i){
        c[i] += a * b[i];
    }

}
```

Comment: Let the compiler do it? https://godbolt.org/z/nGeP46zMc Adding `restrict` helps.

Comment: While this can be done (as shown), can you rearrange the code so that you have all neurons at once, and vectorize across them in a different way? I'm just guessing what you're doing with this, but it may be possible to reduce the number of loads and stores to `c` by reordering the overall computation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GCC already auto-vectorizes that with a check for overlap.  Promising that there's no overlap by using `int *restrict c` lets GCC remove that check, and gets clang to decide to auto-vectorize.

However, clang widens to 32-bit and uses `vpmulld` which is 2 uops on Haswell and later.  (Although it's fully efficient on Zen.)  GCC uses `vpmullw` and `vpmulhw` to get the low and high halves of 16-bit full multiplies, and shuffles those together. ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:60,endLineNumber:3,positionColumn:52,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:60,selectionStartLineNumber:3,startColumn:52,startLineNumber:3),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Avoid+propogate_neuron(const+short+a,+const+int8_t+*restrict+b,+int+*restrict+c)+%7B%0A++++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+32%3B+%2B%2Bi)%7B%0A++++++++c%5Bi%5D+%2B%3D+a+*+b%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.74395315282028,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-march%3Dznver2%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:32.77683459335041,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cclang1300,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-march%3Dhaswell%27,selection:(endColumn:16,endLineNumber:13,positionColumn:16,positionLineNumber:13,selectionStartColumn:9,selectionStartLineNumber:13,startColumn:9,startLineNumber:13),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+13.0.0+(C,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4))  This is a pretty clunky strategy, especially with `-march=znver2` where `vpmulld` is single uop.

GCC does only have four single-uop multiply instructions, but costs a lot of shuffles to achieve it.  We can do better:

---

**Since we only need 8x16 => 32-bit multiplies, we can instead use [`vpmaddwd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmaddwd)** which is single-uop on Haswell/Skylake as well as Zen.  https://uops.info/table.html

Unfortunately we can't take advantage of the add part since we need to add to a full 32-bit value.  We need zeros in the high half of every pair of 16-bit elements to use it as just a 16x16 => 32-bit multiply within each 32-bit element.

```
#include <immintrin.h>

void propogate_neuron_avx2(const short a, const int8_t *restrict b, int *restrict c) {
   __m256i va = _mm256_set1_epi32( (uint16_t)a );    // [..., 0, a, 0, a] 16-bit elements

   for (int i = 0 ; i < 32 ; i+=8) {
       __m256i vb = _mm256_cvtepi8_epi32( _mm_loadl_epi64((__m128i*)&b[i]) );
       __m256i prod = _mm256_madd_epi16(va, vb);
       __m256i sum = _mm256_add_epi32(prod, _mm256_loadu_si256((const __m256i*)&c[i]));
       _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&c[i], sum);
    }
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AB9U8lJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYMQAJlIOAMngMmABy7gBGmMTeGqQADqgKhLYMzm4e3nEJSQIBQaEsEVFeMZaY1slCBEzEBKnunj6l5QKV1QS5IeGR0RZVNXXpjX3tgZ0F3cUAlBaorsTI7BwApF4AzIHIblgA1EurjgoE%2BIIAdAh72EsaAIJX1wBuqHjo27HEqPHATASYxkFzAggaAYh22CgQJAI2yYpG2wNBgQIAA5jFCAFTETCHYh4azbMKwxHbDFYgg4vHISa7ADsACE7ttGdt%2BMRthAiXhdqsACLbDR7WnbTl7RzbVZeAW7Lz06V4SZLOkMpnK5BLACstLw6t5K3pPOhxPx6s12oFSsZCu5d0t1puK3WDE2rh2IrwLBYiJxDDOF1tDyeLzeH1QXx%2Bf0wAIYxiY91UXiBAlB4Mh0Nh8KhiJR6Mx2NxUIJQsExJzZLzcKpCvpNyZphYXjVADZOfcmFzecZ3fWG8YlAQuMZMLE8OKIGzXIiuN2CJNW/LVoKmQB6Re7DUndewmKpvmwpja7aTgC0YUI20w9DYggUfqZLLZHLbfK5guF%2BzFXmfQt1e25SIriurZVGVrLtmzCR8OzrRtjGQe4fiHFFB2HeNtkg4xaFQJh0FoAchwbSQoFrLgvCRPA0XlLwGzCY0tTVbkqTnKtriA4CO1A153heH9UM7aCWCw9BcLwScIBbWF7jCRjzWVEDG05BR3Ag3juwEoSRyDdBYUgrt0Mw9BXB7PAuygdNULYuTyJWBtVQ1Wj6KkwCgO06DDhICNDOMiBZKbSzKJsk06NhBSWAc5imRtO1qStG4OGmWhODVXhPA4LRSFQThRQUWZ5kwKVVh4UgCE0WLpgAaxAVZVhOalJFWABONV8rVEjihI/ROEkJLirSzheAUEAYiKlLYtIOBYCQNAWCHegyAoBMprobpkGALhiL4OgfmIfqIDCbqT2YYgAE9OAKybLwIAB5BhaGO4bSCwfijHEO78Excp7ixbrMFUMpXB%2BE7eERc9utoPAwmIapDucLButLFgAemKgDGABQADU8EwAB3C7YkYAGZEEEQxHYKQCfkJQ1G63QuH0QwTDMfQwf6yBpg%2BGxE04Q8LtWbZD34%2BZzh5AAvBgPuILw%2BvPMp2c8CAHAGTwaf8UZ8kKPR4kSGWFfVrIZY6VXuhppoZdafoXHqPRjYqYZ9a6KIjeGbWHbaW3xnt6YsrmBY9DJTBFh4OKEq6u70o4VQkQbQ98O2YBkGQA8uBOD8IEcWFcEIEg8pp7ZnAWmas8mXghq0SYyoqrxqupBskVWSQ1Tqyq1Q0SQafijhOtIZLUtDvqBsK4rpjGxAUFQPPInIShJumpbNjprhVg0GIaFoTbtt2u79sh/GzsYS7rtu1KHrp57D7wN6bA%2B/q7u%2B37/u4QHBGBu7QfByHocWVK4YRvhkbRjHsdxslAq/BCaiHEKTEB5MVDqDuroHwBgjAgFMDBRmYRmYQFZrEGWV8uY8z5tUZAgtuQICYAoTG55aCSysDLewDAnDm3SErOhrs1Y0w1tkFIDDFaZE1skFhhsLBS2aAwU2tQuGWyESbG2Ks7aW0duI52NR%2BHuxmF7EmhVMT%2BxGm3RKnduqh3DpHaOs8jAHiqhoE4Gg2Sp22OnIgrJ7TZ1ztPBxawvCF37sNUupByqVROJVAJgSgntXbsHbuvULB92LiVEJEs9EhwidE7xYtEh2EkEAA):

```
# clang13.0 -O3 -march=haswell
        movzx   eax, di
        vmovd   xmm0, eax                     # 0:a  16-bit halves
        vpbroadcastd    ymm0, xmm0            # repeated to every element

        vpmovsxbd       ymm1, qword ptr [rsi]  # xx:b 16-bit halves
        vpmaddwd        ymm1, ymm0, ymm1       # 0 + a*b in each 32-bit element
        vpaddd  ymm1, ymm1, ymmword ptr [rdx]
        vmovdqu ymmword ptr [rdx], ymm1

... repeated 3 more times, 8 elements per vector

        vpmovsxbd       ymm1, qword ptr [rsi + 8]
        vpmaddwd        ymm1, ymm0, ymm1
        vpaddd  ymm1, ymm1, ymmword ptr [rdx + 32]
        vmovdqu ymmword ptr [rdx + 32], ymm1
```

If saving a uop per vector multiply makes a measurable performance difference, it might be worth the trouble of manually vectorizing in the source.

It's a missed optimization that GCC / clang don't do this in the first place when auto-vectorizing your pure C code.

If anyone wants to report this, leave a comment here.  Otherwise I might get around to it.  IDK if patterns like this are frequent enough for GCC / LLVM's optimizers to want to look for this pattern.  Especially clang already makes a reasonable choice that's only sub-optimal because of CPU quirks (32x32 => 32-bit SIMD mulitplication costs more on recent Intel microarchitectures than 2x 16x16 => 32-bit with horizontal add).

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `restrict` qualifier to mark `c` that it cannot alias with `b`.

The issue is that `int8_t` is likely `signed char` which can alias with any other type according to strict aliasing rule. Therefore the compiler cannot be sure that setting `c[i]` will not modify `b[i]`.
The forces the compiler to fetch data on every iteration.

Presence of `const` does not mean anything because it only limit programmer from modifying data via pointer `b`.

After replacing the prototype to:

```
void propogate_neuron(const short a, const int8_t *b, int * restrict c)
```

the code gets vectorized. See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nj4jaqxMd)

Comment: A more aggressive compiler could have done an overlap check, and made two versions of the loop (one for overlap, one for the non-overlap case.)  The size is know ahead of the loop.  For example, GCC does that without `restrict`: https://godbolt.org/z/vfx7r5Tfv.  But yes, sometimes compilers just give up unless you use `restrict` (or C++ `__restrict`), and if you know it won't overlap then it helps avoid a wasted length calc + compare/branch.  Also note that you only enabled `-mavx`, not AVX2 + tuning with `-march=haswell` or `znver2`; you get fewer insns: https://godbolt.org/z/hcKszerbK

Comment: Hmm, can we avoid widening to 32-bit for `vpmulld` (2 uops on Haswell and later)?  Maybe still widen `b` to 32-bit elements with `vpmovsx` loads, but use `vpmaddwd` (single uop) to do 16x16-bit widening signed multiply with a vector of `[0, a, 0, a, ...]`, instead of sign-extending `a` to 32-bit.  We still get 32-bit full-multiply results, and add with 0.  That's a missed optimization in the auto-vectorizer, though.

Comment: Added that as an answer.